# Why is there type mismatch when making a POST request using hyper 0.14 over TLS?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

I am trying to construct a POST http request using hyper.
I am using `tokio_rustls` to construct a https connector with tls.

The code I am using is:

```rust
use hyper::{body::to_bytes, client, Body, Method, Uri,Request};

let mut http = client::HttpConnector::new();
http.enforce_http(false);
//set tls configs.
let mut tls = tokio_rustls::rustls::ClientConfig::new();
// initialize http connector
let https = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnector::from((http, tls));
//prepare client with tls settings.
let client: client::Client<_, hyper::Body> = client::Client::builder().build(https);

let fut = async move {
        let req = Request::builder().method(Method::POST)
            .uri("url")
            .body(())
            .unwrap();
        let res = match client.request(req).await {
            Ok(d) => d,
            Method => {
                println!("Invalid method");
                std::process::exit(1);
            }
            TooLarge => {
                println!("Too large");
                std::process::exit(1);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("unable to post {:?} ", e);
                std::process::exit(1);
            }
        };
        println!("Status:\n{}", res.status());
        println!("Headers:\n{:#?}", res.headers());

        let body: Body = res.into_body();
        let body = to_bytes(body)
            .await
            .map_err(|e| error(format!("Could not get body: {:?}", e)))?;
        println!("Body:\n{}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&body));
        // ...
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> examples/client.rs:116:40
    |
116 |         let res = match client.request(req).await {
    |                                        ^^^ expected struct `Body`, found `()`
    |
    = note: expected struct `hyper::Request<Body>`
               found struct `hyper::Request<()>`
```

not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type mismatch occurred exactly in accordance to the requested types declared. Looking again at the definition of `client`:

```
let client: client::Client<_, hyper::Body> = client::Client::builder().build(https);
```

The second type parameter of [`Client`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.13/hyper/client/struct.Client.html#) (known as `B`) stands for the expected body type of all requests made by this client.
In all subsequent calls to [`request`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.13/hyper/client/struct.Client.html#method.request), the body type must match. In this case, it was defined to `hyper::Body`, which is also the default type for `B`. However, the request made next had a body value of type `()`.

```
let req = Request::builder().method(Method::POST)
    .uri("url")
    .body(()) // <--- `()` instead of `Body`
    .unwrap();
```

If there is no future intention to provide more than an empty body in all requests, then it is safe to change the type parameter `B` accordingly, or to let the compiler infer it automatically.

```
let client: client::Client<_, _> = client::Client::builder().build(https);
```

Otherwise, the alternative is to provide an empty body through the function [`Body::empty`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.13/hyper/body/struct.Body.html#method.empty).

```rust
let req = Request::builder().method(Method::POST)
    .uri("url")
    .body(hyper::Body::empty()) // it's a match now
    .unwrap();
```